# Try rake task again at a later time if it fails using whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) and I set up a schedule running at 4:00 AM every day like so in my `schedule.rb` file:

```
every 1.day, at: '4:00am' do
  rake "third_party:get_files"
end
```

The third party service I'm using told me the files will be ready at 4:00 AM. But, for whatever reason, if they happen to not have those files, I want to be able to try again in an hour (or 2) to see if those files are available.

Can I use the whenever gem to achieve that? Or is there another way to do it? I looked around on google but wasn't able to find anything so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is it bad to run the task even if the initial attempt finished successfully?

Comment: The reasoning behind it is we want to have the files and parse the data before users generally would log in, so we'd want it as early as possible. Something weird might be happening at the 3rd party service we're working with, so they might have the files ready a little later but we'd still want to try to grab them automatically. We'll probably email everyone when the 2nd attempt fails and one of us will manually look at it.

Comment: I would set 2 jobs with whenever, if the first one succeeds you can set a value somewhere to let you know the file of that day was proccesed and the second attempt can check that value and retry or do nothing (you can set a timestamp somewhere on the database or touch a file somewhere on your disk to set the current timestamp and check it's last modified time for example).

Comment: @arieljuod Ahh thank you for that suggestion. Somehow I haven't thought of it that way, must be because it's Monday of thanksgiving week haha. I was trying to look for some fancy "railsy" way but I think your suggestion works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: You could also - if you have some background workers - schedule the job N times if files not ready